# Error 1314 when I call AuthzRegisterSecurityEventSource() in Windows 2008 but works in Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

New to windows programming here, and I am looking at code that was written for Windows Server 2003 that fails with Windows Server 2008.

The code essentially does the following:

Calls LookupPrivilageValue(NULL, _T("SeAuditPrivelage"), &luidSeAudit)); to get the LUID struct.

Please note, I check the return code of every API call to make sure no problems are encountered.

It then adjusts the TOKEN_PRIVELAGES:

```
OpenProcessToken(...);
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luidSeAudit;

AjustTokenPrivelages(tokenHandle, FALSE, &tp, 0, NULL, NULL);
CloseHandle(tokenHandle);


GetModuleFileName(NULL, pBuf, 260);
strPath = pBuf;
iRet = strPath.ReverseFind('\\');
strPath = strPath.Left(iRet);
CString strName = strPath;
strName += _T("\\");
strName += _T("MyTool.exe");
_tcscpy_s(pBuf, 260, strName);

AUTHZ_SOURCE_SCHEMA_REGISTRATION ar;
memset(&ar, 0, sizeof(ar));
ar.dwFlags = AUTHZ_ALLOW_MULTIPLE_SOURCE_INSTANCES;
ar.szEventSourceName = _T("MySim");
ar.szEventMessageFile = pBuf;
ar.szEventSourceXmlSchemaFile = NULL;
ar.szEventAccessStringsFile = pBuf;
ar.szExecutableImagePath = NULL;
```

Then I call

```
AuthzInstallSecurityEventSource(0, &ar);
```

No errors here either.

However, when I call:

```
if (!AuthzRegisterSecurityEventSource(0, _T("MySim"), &m_secEvProv)) {
    ....GetLastError()...;
    return Error;
}
```

Note that m_secEvProv is of type: AUTHZ_SECURITY_EVENT_PROVIDER_HANDLE.

I get error 1314:

ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD
1314 (0x522)
A required privilege is not held by the client.

So to that end, what additional steps do I need to take to acquire such privilege in 2008?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the spirit of answering most of my questions, this is yet another example.

In 2008, there are a few things you have to do in the Group Policy Management component.

Perform the following steps:

Start->Administrative Tools->Group Policy Management

Open up your Forest->Domains->->Domain Controllers

Right Click on the entry and choose Edit

[image]

This will open up another window:
[image]

Go to Computer Configuration->Policies->Windows Settings->Security Settings->Local Policies

Then edit Audit Policy as shown in the image or at the very least, modify Audit object access and check all three check boxes: “Define these policy settings”, “Success” and “Failure; click OK button to close the dialog box;

Below it is User Rights Assignments.  Click on that and then click on the Policy: Generate Security audits.

[image]

Add your domain and username, in my case its UIDDEV\Administrator.  This will be the user my program will run under.  Voila!  You have access to modify the security logs.

[image]